# How can I avoid throttling? (or, is there a way to really batch get?)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Looks like my Firestore requests are being throttled! (see picture below)

If I had to guess, I'd say it's not Firestore doing the throttling, it's actually Chrome... I've seen this kind of throttling before.

[image: Throttling in action]

One way to get around Chrome's throttling here is to combine multiple requests into one.

As I sit here thinking "I wonder if Firestore can combine these read requests?", I notice that, coincidentally, the requests to Firestore are actually named batchGet! But oddly enough, each batchGet request only has one read inside it:

[image: It seems batchGet only gets one document]

So, in an effort to avoid Chrome's throttling, my question is: how do I request multiple documents at the same time in Firestore? I suspect it's possible because, well, there's a server endpoint named batchGet. Is it possible?

Many thanks!

Comment: Some extra info: These are all inside of a transaction. And, I tried making the transaction.get calls happen right after each other (not even delayed by Promises' .then() calls) and Firestore didn't group them. Was worth a try!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just dug through the source a bit, looks like it's impossible. Transaction's .get() method looks like this:

```
Transaction.prototype.get = function (documentRef) {
    var _this = this;
    validateExactNumberOfArgs('Transaction.get', arguments, 1);
    var ref = validateReference('Transaction.get', documentRef, this._firestore);
    return this._transaction
        .lookup([ref._key])
        .then(function (docs) {
        if (!docs || docs.length !== 1) {
            return fail('Mismatch in docs returned from document lookup.');
        }
        var doc = docs[0];
        if (doc instanceof NoDocument) {
            return new DocumentSnapshot(_this._firestore, ref._key, null, false);
        }
        return new DocumentSnapshot(_this._firestore, ref._key, doc, false);
    });
};
```

That .lookup() takes an array of all the documents to put into the batchGet request, and it's coded here to only ever have one element in that array.

So, looks like there's no way to get multiple documents in one batchGet request.